# Http Headers as String: Which delimiter to use?

Tags: rest, http, header, delimiter

If I am getting a bunch of HTTP headers as a single string, what is the best delimiter to use to separate each header name/value(s) pair? I have though of using commas but they seem to occur within the value of certain HTTP headers. Is there any character that is not allowed for HTTP headers that I can use ?

Comment: The (mostly) standard way is to split them with a `\r\n`, so a newline!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One straightforward choice would be to use the same delimiter used by HTTP messages themselves. The grammar for messages can be found in [RFC 7230 Section 3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-3):

```
     HTTP-message   = start-line
                      *( header-field CRLF )
                      CRLF
                      [ message-body ]
```

where `CRLF` is [defined](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5234#appendix-B.1) as a carriage return followed by a line feed.

So my suggestion is to use that.